# How to loop through all params without knowing their names

Tags: actionscript-3

I have a few functions that accept several parameters.

```
public function somefunc(param1:String, param2:String, param3:String):void{

}
```

Is there a way to loop through all the params (without knowing how many or their names) and put them in some kind of an array with their names, so I'd get an associative array

```
[
param1: "value 1"
param2: "value 2"
param3: "value 3"
]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The object [arguments](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/arguments.html) stores a function's arguments and you can use the `length` property to get the number of arguments. However it does not provide the names of the arguments, i.e. it won't provide names `param1, param2` etc. It will only provide the values of them.

Comment: I was doing some searching after I posted the question and found `arguments` too. I like it, but how is it different from the `rest` solutions proposed by @package?

Comment: `rest` is more useful when you need variable length arguments, that is you don't know the number of parameters. Think about the `trace` function. It takes variable length arguments, i.e. you can pass any number of arguments to it. `rest` is needed to write this kind of function. If you know the number of arguments to a function while writing that function, rest may not be needed.

Answer (score 2):

You can use rest parameter (`...`) in your function arguments list to accept any amount of arguments and loop through them, like this:

```
 public function somefunc(param1:String, param2:String, param3:String, ... rest):void {
    for (var i:int = 0; i < rest.length; i++) {
        trace(rest[i]);
    }
 }
```

And calling your function looks like this:

```
somefunc(param1, param2, param3, param4, param5, ect);
```

Comment: This is the correct answer. You should use `...rest:*` to make it type-safe.

Comment: but you don't have to do the for-loop - there is the `arguments`-object that already has all the params in it: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/arguments.html